# SQL Complex Query with count

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

[image]

Hi i have a table structure as above image and i need  to take count of several columns into a one single column such as

```
octSecAndthrd1
octSecAndthrd2
octSecAndthrd3   
octSecAndthrd4
```

count of these columns to a **single column** Named **(Column1)** like wise

The Final output should be as:

ID | Column1 | Column2

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Do you want to do like @chris said or do you need some dynamic code? If so, the total number of columns is a multiple of 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id
     , sum(octSecAndthrd1 + octSecAndthrd2 + octSecAndthrd3 + octSecAndthrd4) col1
     , sum(octSecAndthrd5 + octSecAndthrd6 + octSecAndthrd7 + octSecAndthrd8) col2
  from ...
```